FATAL EXCEPTION: main. need operate suspend function result in one method
I have another suspend method in my method and it does not wait until it completes its work
usually, I had such an error when the work did not end. When my updateStudioById method worked a little differently, the error did not appear. The essence of this method is to take data from the Internet and update it if it has changed, delete it if it has not arrived
suspend fun updateStudioById(cityId: String)  : Boolean {
        runCatching {
            remoteDataSource.fetchStudioByCity(cityId).getOrThrow()
                .filter { it.isActive && it.moderationStatus == "moderated" }
        }.onSuccess { data ->
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val city = localDataSource.getCityById(cityGeneralId).firstOrNull()
                if (city != null && city.isDataLoaded) {
                    val localStudios =
                        localDataSource.getStudioByCityId(cityGeneralId).firstOrNull()
                            ?: emptyList()
                    data.forEach {...}
                    val newStudios = data.filter { remoteStudio ->
                        localStudios.none { localStudio -> localStudio.studio.studioId == remoteStudio.id }
                    }
                    if (newStudios.isNotEmpty()) {
                        insertNewStudio(newStudios)
                    }

                    val studiosToDelete = localStudios.filter { localStudio ->
                        localStudio.studio.studioId !in data.map { it.id }

                    }
                    studiosToDelete.forEach {...}
                } else {
                    fetchStudioByCity(cityGeneralId)
                }
            }
        }.onFailure { ex ->
            _errorFlow.tryEmit(Error(ex))
        }
        return true
    }

And...  I want to mention that the method  fetchStudioByCity worked well in another example
    suspend fun fetchStudioByCity(cityId: String): Boolean {
        Log.d("repository", "fetch")
        runCatching {
            remoteDataSource.fetchStudioByCity(cityId).getOrThrow()
                .filter { it.isActive && it.moderationStatus == "moderated" }
        }.onSuccess { data ->
            return insertNewStudio(data)
        }.onFailure { ex ->
            _errorFlow.tryEmit(Error(ex))
        }
        return false
    }

Now i had this error, because data wasn't inserted in database
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process                                                     

I try to use asynk{} block  and wait result, but it didn't works for me

You used runCatching, and since onSuccess is a higher-order function, fetchStudioByCity does not wait for the insertNewStudio operation to complete and may return false prematurely. This causes the coroutine within withContext to finish early, leading to an incomplete job.

could you please use try/catch instead of  runCatching ?

Unfortunately didn't work
